# When I submit a form on my webpage the URL immediately gets updated with its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to forms and copy and pasted this sample code for a login snippet:

```
              <div class="login-form-1">
                <form id="login-form" class="text-left">
                    <div class="main-login-form">
                        <div class="login-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lg_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lg_username" name="lg_username" placeholder="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lg_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lg_password" name="lg_password" placeholder="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group login-group-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="lg_remember" name="lg_remember">
                                <label for="lg_remember">Stay logged in?</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="login-button"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-2x"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

When the user hits submit on the button the URL of the webpage changes from:

> http://localhost:52303/Src/Main/index.html

to

> http://localhost:52303/Src/Main/index.html?username=whatever&password=whatever

What causes this and how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: GET is the default form `method`, so it makes a get request with the given form fields as params.

Comment: @Pipeline, learn about GET and POST parameters. But copying code snippets without understanding and handling log-in data is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `POST` method for the form submission.

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" class="text-left">
```

By default, it uses `GET` method,which will send the form data via query string values. In your example, `username` and `password` are two form fields( the name values of the form fields) and they are being send when you submit the form.

*From MDN,documentation about the `method` property of `form`,*

The HTTP method that the browser uses to submit the form. Possible values are:

**post**: Corresponds to the HTTP POST method ; form data are included in the body of the form and sent to the server.

**get**: Corresponds to the HTTP GET method; form data are appended to the action attribute URI with a '?' as separator, and the resulting URI is sent to the server. Use this method when the form has no side-effects and contains only ASCII characters.

Submitting form data via GET method is not ideal as number of characters in query strings has a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what happens when you submit the form, the form details i.e the textbox or any other controls are posted

Check this link for more answers

[How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)